# Recursively rename folders based on contents in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rename

I have a collection of folders (within a folder) that all need to be renamed based on their contents.

Specifically, I'd like to rename "/working_directory/my_folder/my_file.extension" to /working_directory/my_file/my_file.extension"

There are a few other files within /my_folder/. How might I recursively do this using ruby?

I'm new to ruby and programming, I have so tried to just extract the file names, but have not have much luck.  The attempt at itterating through the folders.  This will cycle through /working_directory/ every time Find.find is called.  The intent is to search /working_directory/my_folder/ only for the file with the .fls extension.

```
require 'find'
Path = "/working_directory/"
Dir.foreach(Path) do |file|
 puts file
 new_dir = Path+file
 puts new_dir
 Find.find(new_dir) do |i| # this is intended to by /working_directory/my_folder/
  fls_file << i if i =~ /.*\.fls$/
  puts fls_file
  end
end
```

Comment: You want to rename folders and files ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, the `my_file` is to be chosen by `extension`, one might do:

```
Dir["/working_directory/**/*"].select do |dir_or_file|
  File.directory? dir_or_file # select only directories, recursively
end.inject({}) do |memo, dir|
  new_name = Dir["#{dir}/*.extension"].to_a
  unless new_name.size == 1 # check if the folder contains only one proper file
    puts "Multiple/No choices; can not rename dir [#{dir}] ⇒ skipping..."
    next memo # skip if no condition met
  end
  my_file = new_name.first[/[^\/]+(?=\.extension\z)/] # get my_name
  memo[dir] = dir.gsub /[^\/]+(?=\/#{myfile}\.extension\z)/, my_file
  memo
end.each do |old, neu|
  # dry run to make sure everything is OK 
  puts "Gonna rename #{old} to #{neu}"
  # uncomment the lines below as you are certain the code works properly
  # neu_folder = neu[/(.*?)([^\/]+\z)/, 1]
  # FileUtils.mkdir neu_folder unless File.exist? neu_folder
  # FileUtils.mv old, neu # rename
end
```

The rename is done after the main processing for the sake of previous iterator consistency, probably in this case it might be done in the previous loop, instead of injecting `old: neu` pairs into hash and iterating it later.

We are heavily using string parsing with regexps here.

```
  my_file = new_name.first[/[^\/]+(?=\.extension\z)/] # get my_name
```

this line gets a new folder name by parsing a tail of the string, containing no slashes and trailing with `'.extension\z'` (see positive lookahead.)

```
  memo[dir] = dir.gsub /[^\/]+(?=\/#{myfile}\.extension\z)/, my_file
```

This line assigns a new element on an accumulator hash, substituting the old folder name with the new one.

Comment: Thanks for posting up the code.  Doesn't quite work out of the box and doing my best to trouble shoot.  New name will capture the "/my_file.extension", but end.each arguments |old,neu| both return "dir_or_file".  I suspect it is in 'code' my_file = new_name.first[/[^\/]+(?=\.fls\z)/] # get my_name
  memo[dir] = dir.gsub /[^\/]+(?=\/#{my_file}\.fls\z)/, my_file 'code'  Can you explain these lines?

Comment: It does work for me. Do you have a destination folder created? If no, there might be a need to create it in the code (see update.) Regarding two lines to explain, please see an update as well.